# Is this good results for my django webserver?

Tags: nginx, web-server, django

I bought a new server to migrate my site because the former are experiencing delays from time to time. I'm doing some tests with AB to check how good is this new server, and would like hear from you!

Today I'm running: nginx + fcgi (Django).

The server has this setting:

Intel (R) Xeon (R) CPU X3440@2.53GHz 8 colors
8GB DDR3 RAM
1 TB RAID 1 + 60GB SSD

I'm running a mysql on SSD and the rest of the operating system on RAID 1.

Here the results of my homepage AB:

```
[root@usloft2613 ~]# ab -n 1000 -c 20 http://50.30.32.155/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.0.40-dev <$Revision: 1.146 $> apache-2.0
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Copyright 2006 The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 50.30.32.155 (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        nginx/0.8.55
Server Hostname:        50.30.32.155
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        218 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   24.505647 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        909
   (Connect: 0, Length: 909, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      929
Total transferred:      61143197 bytes
HTML transferred:       60979957 bytes
Requests per second:    40.81 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       490.113 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       24.506 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2436.58 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       1
Processing:   116  482 609.7    288    6157
Waiting:      115  480 609.4    283    6156
Total:        116  482 609.7    288    6157

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    288
  66%    358
  75%    438
  80%    541
  90%   1078
  95%   1801
  98%   2399
  99%   3060
 100%   6157 (longest request)
```

The part that I usually look at is this:  Requests per second:    40.81 [#/sec] (mean).
.

This number is good for my server hardware?

This means that my site can handle 40 simultaneous users?

Is there any other important data of AB should I consider?

I hope with this server support 100 + online users, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes?  No?  What if each page request was calculating the billionth Fibonacci number from scratch?  Or what if they were just image loads?  Without any idea about what kind of workload you're doing, nobody can say.

That being said, it does NOT mean you can handle 40 simultaneous *users*.  It means you can handle 40 simultaneous *requests*.  So if you had 100 online users making a request every 2.5 seconds, you'd be able to handle that.  You will need to look at your traffic patterns and see what kind of traffic you can expect--many stats libraries will tell you the requests per second based on you access log, so that might be a good place to start.